# Ubuntu slow on old laptop with some non working keys

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I put ubuntu 17.04 on an old laptop that i want to donate to somebody as windows was already slow on it

1. laptop was very slow after installing ubuntu especially the animations so i disabled them all. still its a little less than usable
2. i have my backspace key and underscore/hyphen key not working (**this is the primary question**) and i want to know how do i remap them to *pausebreak* and *insert* keys (since i can't know their key codes what should i do?)

also can i disable some more features so as to make it a bit more usable or should i consider lubuntu

Comment: lubuntu is probably the best option

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to say this here or not, I ran through this situation many times before. The best choices I figured out (after many trials) are - fedora and xubuntu. I know lubuntu is known for light-weight, but believe me it is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about the functionality of the keyboard (you can try an external keyboard first), The problem may be that the key "Back" was assigned to another action. Try removing the shortcut following the steps found here [https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155436/backspace-key-not-working)

To change the key or keys to be pressed for a keyboard shortcut:

1. Click the system menu Power cog icon and select System Settings.
2. Open Keyboard and select the Shortcuts tab.
3. Select a category in the left pane, and the row for the desired action on the right. The current shortcut definition will change to New accelerator…
4. Hold down the desired key combination, or press Backspace to clear.

Comment: i don't understand . is this the solution in case my keyboard is working properly and there is something wrong with the software?

Comment: To make sure that your keyboard is working properly, you can check connecting an external keyboard that you know is working correctly, and use the keys with the problems, if the problem persists, this means your problem relies in software, then you can follow the above solution - otherwise, you can consult a hardware specialist.

Answer (score 0):

I think **Lubuntu** or **Puppy Linux** is a better option for you. Modern Ubuntu is very demanding in hardware and old version is not recommended.

I am pretty sure that your keyboard must have degraded to a very bad state over this time, so prefer an external keyboard (*suggest the person you are giving this laptop to.*) or change the Laptop's keyboard if available for that model. Typing with a missing backspace button is a real pain.

Comment: so you don't know how to remap keys of which i don't have the key codes?

Comment: sorry ! Unfortunately i don't

Comment: @Ishan Srivastava Were your keys working in windows?